Use Devtools inspector without jumping back to Elements window
When one selects an element using the Inspector in the devtools, the Elements window is opened. Is it possible to prevent the Devtools from giving focus to the Elements window? I want the focus to remain on my own window (devtools extension).

Not possible inherently but you can use/write an external utility that restores the focus or there may be such an option in some linux desktop environment.
